# Writing custom UDF in spark on a List to get Index

Tags: apache-spark

I need to write a UDF in scala that will take the the column name and return the Index of each element in the List.
For Example

Input Dataframe

```
name
[a,b,c]
[c,d,e]
[m,b]
.
.
.
```

Output Dataframe

```
|name    | distance |
----------------------
|[a,b,c] | [0,1,2]
|[c,d,e] | [0,1,2]
|[m,b]   | [0,1]
|[z]     | [0]
|.       |
|.       |
```

Code I have written so far which does not work

```
def authorDistance(name : List[String]) ={
   (0 to name.length).toList
}


val authorD = udf((s: List[String]) => authorDistance(s))

val transform1 = transform0.withColumn("distance", authorD(transform0("name")))
```

I am new to spark. Help appreciated. Thanks

EDIT : Error message

```
at PreProcessingUtil.main(PreProcessingUtil.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: scala.MatchError: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive (of class scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeRef$$anon$6)
```

Comment: and what is the problem? "does not work" means what - exception? wrong results? (show us!)

Comment: You've been posting questions for a while now, and the way you ask is seriously problematic. Please read the following page on [how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ! It kind a sounds that you want other to do your homework for you.

Comment: Well I have made an edit. Let me know if its okay.

Comment: @eliasah I am quite passionate about what I do. Some people a good at finding faults and some wise people are genuinely interested in improving / helping people by giving genuine feedback. Why is my question problematic?.

Comment: Well then, at least, take some time to read the link in my last comment so these genuine people can help you better. And sometimes, before posting a question, try to solve the question yourself ! It's good practice.

Comment: @eliasah Anyway thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am writing the basic function to do the same task , you can mold it for your requirement.

Define a List:

```
val list = List("a","b","c","d")
```

Define the udf:

```
def authorDistance(name : List[String]) ={ name.zipWithIndex.map(_._2)}
```

Apply UDF:

```
authorDistance(list)
```

Result:

```
res55: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 2, 3)
```